# PHP preg_match - capturing attributes that use either double or single quotes

Tags: php, preg-match, quotes

I have a regular expression that looks into HTML files and finds elements based off if they match a regular expression I pass in. One main thing that determines if the element is matched is what the id is. The id has to be some special characters that I decided to use. The problem is, I know that some people will use either double OR single quotes when writing ids in HTML. I want to be able to catch either case. So my regular expression is this:

```
preg_match('@(<)([^\s]*).*(id)\s*=\s*["|\']{{ALViewElement_'.$viewElement.'}}["|\'][^/]*?(>)@i', $viewFile, $elementMatches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)
```

Close to the middle you'll see where I have `id`. After the equals sign I have `["|\']` and then at the end I have the same thing for the closing quote.

If my html looks like this, I get a match:

```
<section  id="{{ALViewElement_resume}}" data-test="testing" >
            <!--{{RESUME_ADD_CHANGE_PIECE}}-->
            <!--{{RESUME}}-->
        </section>
```

However, if I use single quotes instead, it doesn't match:

```
<section  id='{{ALViewElement_resume}}' data-test="testing" >
            <!--{{RESUME_ADD_CHANGE_PIECE}}-->
            <!--{{RESUME}}-->
        </section>
```

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with my regular expression that it won't pick up the single quotes. Any ideas?

Comment: Dont use RegEx to parse HTML/XML documents. Use DOM or XPath.

Comment: What I'm doing has proven much easier using RegEx than DOM or XPath. I explored both options.

Comment: If its easier you wouldn't ask it here, do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I give you a general answer, then you can adapt it to your case. To match single or double quotes, the tricks are:

1) use a backreference (`\1` refer to the capture group 1):

the simple method with a lazy quantifier:

`(["']).*?\1`

the optimised and safer method (deals with escaped quotes):

`(["'])(?>[^"']|["'](?<!\1)|(?<=\\)\1)*+\1`

2) use an alternation:

`(?>"....."|'.....')`

interesting variant with capture groups:

`(?|"...(###)..."|'...(###)...')`

and the two capture groups have the same number.

Notice: the problem doesn't come from your pattern.

Comment: Well I see what you're doing here is assuring that the first quote will match the second quote used. While that's good, that's not really my problem. I think, though not sure, my problem is something to do with the \ I use in front of my single quotes. I have to have it because my preg_match uses single quotes. Right now I'm not concerned if the first quote used matches the second quote used.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the problem doesn't come from my pattern. Could you explain please?

Comment: @user1513171: I have tested your pattern with both cases and it works

Comment: You have tested it with exactly what I posted in the original post?

Comment: Then I'm not sure what the problem is. My exact code if just that preg match in an if and when I have double quotes in my html it gets in the if and when I change it to single quotes I don't get in the if.

Comment: The problem was the $viewElement variable wasn't being populated correctly for ids with single quotes. Fixed. Thanks!